# How to perform the following ordered subset element test in Python?

Tags: python, python-2.7, dictionary, set, subset

I have a dictionary (called dict) whose keys are strings that represent features' names, and whose values are floating-point numbers that denote the counts of each feature.

Here is an example of my dictionary (dict):

{'11268-238-1028': 2.0, '1028': 10.0, '10295': 2.0, '1781': 2.0, '11268-238': 3.0, '6967-167': 1.0, '9742-232-788': 1.0, '8542': 4.0, '238-1028': 5.0, '1028-122': 1.0}

In this example, '10295' is considered as a one-degree feature, '6967-167' is considered as a two-degree feature, and '9742-232-788' is a three-degree feature. If we have 'x-x-x-x-x-x-x', then it would be a seven-degree feature. In other words, for any n-degree feature, that feature has (n-1) dashes ('-').

'11268-238-1028': 2.0 indicates that the 3-degree feature '11268-238-1028' has a count of 2. Then we see that '11268-238': 3.0, which means '11268-238' occurs for 3 times. However, this is some double count problem, because out of the 3 times of occurrence of '11268-238', 2 of them are actually due to the occurrence of '11268-238-1028'. Therefore, we want to change the count of '11268-238' to be its real count, which is 3-2 = 1.

Similarly, the real count of '238-1028' is not 5, because '238-1028' is part of '11268-238-1028', and '11268-238-1028' has a count of 2. So, the real count of '238-1028' should be (5-2 = 3).

Another example is for the feature '1028', its real count should not be 10. '1028' is part of the 3-degree feature '11268-238-1028', which has a count of 2. '1028' is also part of the 2-degree feature '238-1028' whose count is 5. '1028' is also part of the 2-degree feature '1028-122' whose count is 1. Therefore, the real count of the 1-degree feature '1028' should be (10-2-5-1 = 2).

What kind of algorithms should I use to solve this problem?

I thought about converting each key to a set of 1-degree features splitted by dash, and then for each set, do subset membership test against all the other sets with higher length. However, set stores unordered elements, but I care about the order. For example, feature '11268-238-1028' converted to set would be (['11268', '238', '1028']); another feature '11268-1028' converted to set would be (['11268', '1028']). If I perform subset test on these 2 features' sets, I would conclude that (['11268', '1028']) is a subset of (['11268', '238', '1028']). However, the feature '11268-1028' is NOT a subset of the feature '11268-238-1028', because in between '11268' and '1028', there is another thing '238', i.e. order should matter.

How may I solve this problem then?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: have you tried anything yet?

Comment: Do not convert to set but split into list like l='11268-238-1028' and l.split('-') and compare consecutively

Comment: you dont  even need to do that ...

Comment: or check if it is a substring

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should be much easier to prevent double counting when the dict was first created than to undo it later.

But suppose the dict cannot be re-created. Here is a solution. It does not assume that for every higher degree feature there is guaranteed to be a lower degree counterpart for each degree (that is, for a feature A1-A2-...-An, you may be missing any of A1, A1-A2, etc., up to A1-A2-...-An-1). Some `try-except` can be simplified away if this assumption actually holds.

```
def undo_double_counting(d):
    sorted_features = sorted(d, key=lambda f: f.count('-'), reverse=True)
    for f in sorted_features:
        if '-' not in f:
            return d
        feature_below, _ = f.rsplit('-', 1)
        while True:
            try:
                d[feature_below] -= d[f]
            except KeyError:
                # if the feature one degree below isn't actually in d,
                # we keep trying lower degrees until we know that we
                # can't go lower any more (by hitting ValueError)
                try:
                    feature_below, _ = feature_below.rsplit('-', 1)
                except ValueError:
                    break
            else:
                break
    # if there are no degree-1 features in d, return here
    return d
```

Trying it on your data (btw, why float, not int?):

```
{'1028': 9.0,
 '1028-122': 1.0,
 '10295': 2.0,
 '11268-238': 1.0,
 '11268-238-1028': 2.0,
 '1781': 2.0,
 '238-1028': 5.0,
 '6967-167': 1.0,
 '8542': 4.0,
 '9742-232-788': 1.0}
```

Answer (score 1):

break your problem into smaller less complex problems

first lets write a helper function that will actually adjust our data dictionary

```
# this assumes we have one big feature (ie 3) and several smaller features(ie 2&1)
def adjust_data(big_feature,smaller_features,data):
    for feature in smaller_features:
        if feature.count("-") == big_feature.count("-"):
           continue # skip any features that are the same size as our target
        #3 cases for a sub feature it starts with ends with or is contained
        # we use delimiters to eliminate partial matches
        does_start = big_feature.startswith(feature+"-") 
        does_end = bigfeature.endswith("-"+feature) 
        does_contain = "-"+feature+"-" in big_feature
        if does_start or does_end or does_contain :
            # one of our cases match so this is a sub feature of our big feature
            data[feature] -= data[big_feature]
```

now before working with this we would need to organize our data so that it is appropriately sorted.

```
 sorted_keys = sorted(my_data_dict.keys(),
                      key=lambda key:key.count("-"), 
                      reversed=True) #we want bigger features on top
```

now just walk down our sorted data_list

```
  for i,key in enumerate(sorted_keys,1):
      adjust_data(key,sorted_keys[i:],my_data_dict)
```

this is just brute force so its not going to be all that fast but it will get the job done